# Possible race condition or programmer error in Google Fitness startSession

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am attempting to record Google Fit Sessions for periods in sports activity in my Referee Watch. I start a session at the beginning of a period and then stop it at the end of the period.

I *sometimes* get an interesting exception when I start a Fitness session using this code:

```
       private Session startFitSession(final Game currentGame) {
        final Session fitSession;
        try {
            String sessionBaseName =  currentGame.getGameTitle();
            if (sessionBaseName.isEmpty()) sessionBaseName = currentGame.getGameLocation();
            if (sessionBaseName.isEmpty()) sessionBaseName = RefWatchUtil.timeMsToString(currentGame.getActualStartMs(),RefWatchUtil.dateTimeFormatStart);

            final String sessionName = sessionBaseName +  ": "
                    + String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.fitness_period_label),mCurrentPeriod);
            //use this to try to avoid error message about creating a session in the future
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);
            fitSession = new Session.Builder()
                    .setName(sessionName)
                    .setIdentifier(sessionName)
                    .setDescription(mCurrentGame.getGameDescription())
                    .setStartTime(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setActivity(FitnessActivities.RUNNING_JOGGING)
                    .build();

            Fitness.SessionsApi.startSession(mGoogleApiClient, fitSession)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully started Session " + sessionName);
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem starting the session " + sessionName
                                    + ": " + status.getStatusMessage());
                        }
                    }
            });

        } catch (RuntimeException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "There was a runtime exception starting the session: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return fitSession;
    }
```

The exception is:
`There was a runtime exception starting the session: Cannot start a session in the future`

So it occurred to me that perhaps Session.Builder() looks at the "present" as when the new Builder() call, so I changed to the following code:

```
 ...
 final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            fitSession = new Session.Builder()
                    .setName(sessionName)
                    .setIdentifier(sessionName)
                    .setDescription(mCurrentGame.getGameDescription())
                    .setStartTime(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
 ...
```

Same error.

So now I subtract an arbitrary 10 seconds from the startTime and that seems to have fixed the problem.

But (a) is there a better way of making this call (afaict, you can't call setStartTime with a 0 argument to get "current time") and (b) is this a common pattern for Builder type calls?

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution for the same?